# How to fetch doc on basis of the existence of another document in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I have a collection with name post and I have one doc and its replicated doc but in replicated doc we have one field different ,some doc don't have replicated doc and that situation depends on an array field of the doc ,if that field have the userId of user then the replicated doc will exist otherwise it will not exist.

So what I want if the doc array have that id then get the replicated post and if not then original post

I have made the query but showing error I am using $exist in $cond ?

```
Post.aggregate([
        {
            $match: {
                socomo_visibility: socomoId
            }
        },
        {
            $project: {
                "post_stream_type": {
                    $cond: {
                        if: {
                            'following_users_list': {
                                $exist: [userId]
                            }

                        },
                        then: constants.POST_STREAM_TYPE.FOLLOW.value,
                        else: constants.POST_STREAM_TYPE.SOCIAL_CURRY_CHANNEL.value
                    }
                }

            }
  }

                           ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay finally I have done this without using the aggregation .
my answer for the query is

```
  Post.find({
    $or: [{
            socomo_visibility: {
                $elemMatch: {
                    $eq: socomoId
                }
            },
            post_stream_type: constants.POST_STREAM_TYPE.SOCIAL_CURRY_CHANNEL.value,
            following_users_list: {
                $exists: true,
                $nin: [userId]
            }
        },
        {
            socomo_visibility: {
                $elemMatch: {
                    $eq: socomoId
                }
            },
            post_stream_type: constants.POST_STREAM_TYPE.FOLLOW.value,
            following_users_list: {
                $elemMatch: {
                    $eq: userId
                }
            }
        }]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether your array has some value in the boolean-expression in such way:

1. Do intersection of array and value using [$setIntersection](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/setIntersection/).
2. Check size of that intersection array using [$size](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/).
3. If the size is greater than 0 then value is present in the array. [$gt](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/gt/) will do this check.

Try the following code:

```
Post.aggregate([
  {
   $project: { 
    "post_stream_type": {
      $cond: { 
        if: {$gt: [{$size: {$setIntersection: ["$following_users_list", [userId]] } }, 0] }, 
        then: constants.POST_STREAM_TYPE.FOLLOW.value, 
        else: constants.POST_STREAM_TYPE.SOCIAL_CURRY_CHANNEL.value  
      } 
    }  
   }
  }
])
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort .I have tried this but its returning two  fields of all the data _id and post_stream_name. I want if original doc arrray have userId then get the post_stream_type:POST_STREAM_TYPE.FOLLOW.value  for that parent_id otherwise get the original one for that parent id .parent_id is same for both original and replicate but their stream_type is different.